# How to resolve missing characters bug in Cypress type() command?

Tags: cypress

I have a problem regarding typing into the search field of the select2 element. In some tests random character is missing while executing type() command. I tried to wait() before start typing and type with timeout after each character but nothing helped. So the bypass implemented by me is putting the string into the field as a whole instead of typing it char by char:

```
this.getSelect2Input().invoke('val', str).trigger('change')
```

but in this case the test does not understand that the string has been input and continue to wait for input. So the solution was to add a space at the end of the string:

```
this.getSelect2Input().invoke('val', str).trigger('change').type(' ');
```

It works but not for the all tests as in some cases the space is treated as additional character and the string can not be found. For this case I can't found nothing else then typing a space and deleting it (I know that this is not good solution, but what can I do?):

```
this.getSelect2Input().invoke('val', str).trigger('change').type(' {backspace}');
```

But now this is not working as well as in some cases the space is printed but is not deleted. Can anybody advice how to initiate select2 search after setting the value of the field? type({'enter'}) does not work as well.

Comment: What does `this.getSelect2Input()` return ?

Comment: Hi, @AlapanDas  This is  just a page object method getSelect2Input() {return cy.get([element selector here])} you can think about it as a general cy.get() method. And  regarding your answer: as you can see, in my question I mentioned that I tried the solution recommended by you but it did not work.

Comment: Did you use `delay` and `timeout` both followed by `should`. It is not mentioned in the question?

Comment: No, I used just delay without should and wait before start typing. Why do I need to use should? Do you mean that the test will repeat typing if the assertion fails?

Comment: .using should will make sire that cypress will retry untill the value that you are typing matches the value that is typed.

Answer (score 5):

If `this.getSelect2Input()` translates into something `cy.get('locator')`, you can add a [delay](https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions) with [type()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments) and also add `.should` to make sure the intended value that you're typing is typed correctly.

```
// Delay each keypress by 0.1 sec
this.getSelect2Input().type('slow.typing@email.com', {
    delay: 100
}).should('have.value', 'slow.typing@email.com')
```

Or, You can also add a `timeout`:

```
// Add a timeout of 10 seconds
this.getSelect2Input().type('slow.typing@email.com', {
    timeout: 10000
}).should('have.value', 'slow.typing@email.com')
```